# how to handle long running request in akka http route

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

i am using akka http one of my routes is interacting with an external service via akka http client side api and the httpRequest is continuously running i am unable to make it work
here is my use case -> i am interacting with a janus server and doing a long poll get request as soon as the server responded back with an  'keepAlive' or an "event" i am requesting again and so on the server keeps on responding

all of this is happening inside an actor and i have an akka htttp route which is intiailising the first request

here is my code

```
final case class CreateLongPollRequest(sessionId:BigInt)
class LongPollRequestActor (config: Config) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case CreateLongPollRequest(sessionId) =>
      senderRef = Some(sender())
      val uri: String = "localhost:8080/" + sessionId
      val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, uri)
      val responseFuture = Http(context.system).singleRequest(request)
      responseFuture
        .onComplete {
          case Success(res)
          Unmarshal(res.entity.toStrict(40 seconds)).value.map { result =>
              val responseStr = result.data.utf8String
              log.info("Actor LongPollRequestActor: long poll responseStr {}",responseStr)
              senderRef match {
                case Some(ref) =>
                  ref ! responseStr
                case None => log.info("Actor LongPollRequestActor: sender ref is null")
              }
            }
          case Failure(e) =>log.error(e)
          }
          }
          }


final case class JanusLongPollRequest(sessionId: BigInt)
class JanusManagerActor(childMaker: List[ActorRefFactory => ActorRef]) extends Actor {
  var senderRef: Option[akka.actor.ActorRef] = None
  val longPollRequestActor  = childMaker(1)(context)
  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case JanusLongPollRequest(sessionId)=>
      senderRef = Some(sender)
      keepAlive(sessionId,senderRef)
}

  

    def keepAlive(sessionId:BigInt,sender__Ref: Option[ActorRef]):Unit= {
        val senderRef = sender__Ref
        val future = ask(longPollRequestActor, CreateLongPollRequest(sessionId)).mapTo[String] //.pipeTo(sender)
    if (janus.equals("keepalive")) {
                val janusRequestResponse = Future {
                  JanusSessionRequestResponse(janus = janus)
                }
                senderRef match {
                  case Some(sender_ref) =>
                    janusRequestResponse.pipeTo(sender_ref)
                }
                keepAlive(sessionId,senderRef)
              }
              else if (janus.equals("event")) {
               //some fetching of values from server 
                val janusLongPollRequestResponse = Future {
                  JanusLongPollRequestResponse(janus = janus,sender=sender, transaction=transaction,pluginData=Some(pluginData))
                }
                senderRef match {
                  case Some(sender_ref) =>
                    janusLongPollRequestResponse.pipeTo(sender_ref)
                }
                keepAlive(sessionId,senderRef)
              }



def createLongPollRequest: server.Route =
    path("create-long-poll-request") {
      post {
entity(as[JsValue]) {
          json =>
            val sessionID = json.asJsObject.fields("sessionID").convertTo[String]
        
          val future = ask(janusManagerActor, JanusLongPollRequest(sessionID)).mapTo[JanusSessionRequestResponse]
            onComplete(future) {
              case Success(sessionDetails) =>
                    log.info("janus long poll request created")
                    val jsonResponse = JsObject("longpollDetails" -> sessionDetails.toJson)
                    complete(OK, routeResponseMessage.getResponse(StatusCodes.OK.intValue, ServerMessages.JANUS_SESSION_CREATED, jsonResponse))
                
              case Failure(ex) =>
                failWith(ex)
            }
  
           }
          }
```

now the above route `createLongPollRequest` worked fine for the first time I can see the response and for the next attempts i am getting a dead letter as follows

```
[INFO] [akkaDeadLetter][07/30/2021 12:13:53.587] [demo-Janus-ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://demo-Janus-ActorSystem/deadLetters] Message [com.ifkaar.lufz.janus.models.janus.JanusSessionRequestResponse] from Actor[akka://demo-Janus-ActorSystem/user/ActorManager/ManagerActor#-721316187] to Actor[akka://demo-Janus-ActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://demo-Janus-ActorSystem/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

probably this is causing the issue after the first iteration
responseFuture.pipeTo(sender()

IS there a way where i can get a response in my akkahttp route when ever my backend server responds?

Answer (score 0):

The Actor should only reply once to the `CreateLongPollRequest` and it should only do this when it has valid data. If the poll fails the Actor should just issue another poll request.

It is difficult to give more help without the details of the Actor.